# Lightning Out Error : getting "Main:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: $Lightning is not defined" from Heroku App or Node js module

Tags: lightning, connected-apps, heroku-connect, node-salesforce, lighting-out

I have an lightning out app that is using lwc code to get data from salesforce. Now I am accessing it from node.js local and it is not working. Throwing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $Lightning is not defined"?

[image: Node JS Code]

The app is in my development sandbox with code

```
  <aura:application access="GLOBAL" description="ExposedForExternalUsers" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">

    <aura:dependency resource="c:helloWorld"/>
</aura:application>
```

Connected app is here as well and got the access token from it using postman.
[image: Connected App]

Still getting the error as **$Lightning is not defined**. Not sure what is the issue.
[image: Error]

Oauth callback is also authenticating but same error. Also, I directly passed the access token in the code as well but still getting the error.
[image: Auth]

I added local host in remote site settings, CORS, csp.

It works directly with VF page but not on external webpage. Tried same in heroku as well but same error. Any suggessions.

I referred this article for localhost:- http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/use-lightning-components-on-external-websites-lightning-out/

Referred this for Heroku:- https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/mereddyharshitha/lightning-out-heroku